# Is it possible to save a fernet key for a later session?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, cryptography, python-cryptography

I am very new at python, I was working on a program that encrypts a text string, then saves it to a file. My program works perfectly when I encrypt then decrypt it in the same session. What I would like to do is: encrypt a file, then close the program, come back to it later and decrypt it. 
I don't know how the cryptography module works, but judging how it is called the "key" I assume it would be important for security, but I do not know. 
When I try to save the fernet key to a text file it displays an error message. When I try to decrypt a message that was encrypted in a previous session it displays 4 errors referencing the cryptography module.
To conclude, I was wondering if it is possible to use the cryptography module to decrypt data between sessions. If not, is there an alternate way I could complete this task?
Thanks for any help.
here is my code:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)
sel = input("Would you like to encrypt or decrypt? (1 = encrypt, 2 = decrypt) ")
if sel == 1:
    inp = raw_input("Enter Text: ")  # Type here
    encoded = f.encrypt(inp)
    a, b = encoded[:len(encoded)/2], encoded[len(encoded)/2:]
    print ("YOUR PASSWORD: ")
    print b
    file = open('password.txt', 'w')
    file.write(a)
elif sel == 2:
    inp = raw_input("Enter Password: ")
    file = open('password.txt', 'r')
    a = file.readline()
    combine = (a + inp)
    out = f.decrypt(combine)
    print out
```

here is the error that occurs when you enter a "password" from a previous session:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Zak/PycharmProjects/Password/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    out = f.decrypt(combine)
  File "/Users/Zak/PycharmProjects/Password/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 75, in decrypt
    return self._decrypt_data(data, timestamp, ttl)
  File "/Users/Zak/PycharmProjects/Password/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 119, in _decrypt_data
    self._verify_signature(data)
  File "/Users/Zak/PycharmProjects/Password/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 108, in _verify_signature
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

Also this is what happens when you edit the code to save the key to a blank .txt file. Keep in mind this error does not reflect the code above.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Zak/PycharmProjects/Password/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    file.write(f)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Comment: Hey! Could you please post your code to give more context? It is possible to decrypt the message later if you save the key that was used for encryption, like shown in this Python example: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/ Without code or exact error message I cannot tell what can be wrong with your code, so pasting your code here would be appreciated as I could try and reproduce it myself. Thanks!

Comment: @korsosa I updated the question, hopefully that will clarify more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a few modifications, your script can be made to work the way you intended (but read the answer until the end to learn why this might no be an entirely good idea):

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
sel = input("Would you like to encrypt or decrypt? (1 = encrypt, 2 = decrypt) ")
if sel == 1:
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    print ("YOUR KEY: ")
    print key
    f = Fernet(key)
    inp = raw_input("Enter Text: ")  # Type here
    encoded = f.encrypt(inp)
    with open('encoded.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(encoded)
elif sel == 2:
    inp = raw_input("Enter Key: ")
    f = Fernet(inp)
    with open('encoded.txt', 'r') as file:
        encoded = file.readline()
    out = f.decrypt(encoded)
    print out
```

Testing it:

```
$ python2 test.py 
Would you like to encrypt or decrypt? (1 = encrypt, 2 = decrypt) 1
YOUR KEY: 
gRNCcDPDnSzqT2RT4nFJA6MYtsJkBG85sMEy9TogRYg=
Enter Text: This is a secret
$ python2 test.py 
Would you like to encrypt or decrypt? (1 = encrypt, 2 = decrypt) 2
Enter Key: gRNCcDPDnSzqT2RT4nFJA6MYtsJkBG85sMEy9TogRYg=
This is a secret
```

You may have noticed that I changed the word `PASSWORD` into `KEY` -- because that long string of characters is actually the key (in a URL-safe, base64-encoded form) used for the `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` transformations.

In practice, this is normally not what you would be doing. The key can not be memorized and people would typically store it somewhere in a file and use copy-paste to enter it. This increases the risk that the key will leak.

As an alternative, a so-called key-derivation mechanism can be used. In that case, the `key` bytes are not generated randomly with the `Fernet.generate_key()` function, but they are calculated using a key-derivation function that is applied to a, easier to memorize but well-chosen, passphrase. For an example of that, see the section [Using passwords with Fernet](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet.html#using-passwords-with-fernet).

Answer (score 0):

You got the error because same key will be used(already generated when encrypted the file) when you decrypt the file.

But in your case when you are decrypting you are generating the new key that is why you got invalid token error.

This issue can be resolved when you encrypt the file obviously you will generate the key then please write this key into a file using file handling and when you decrypt dont use key = generate_key() method instead use that file in read mode to read the previous key.